# Cyrillic URL Slug on Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, slug, cyrillic

I've found that I cannot use Cyrillic slugs in codeigniter.
Here are some examples of the code:

Routes.php has this:

```
$route['^(ru)/'.rawurldecode('О-нас')] = 'pages/view/nosotros';
```

This is what the HREF has in the HTML

```
<?php echo base_url('/').$this->lang->lang().'/'.rawurldecode(str_replace(' ', '-' , strtolower($this->lang->line('menu_2'))));?>
```

This is a fragment of my "static_text_lang.php" in Russian

`$lang['menu_2'] = 'О нас';`

I've searched a lot and nothing works.
Help me, please!
Thank you! :D

PS: If you need further information, ask me! ^^

Comment: Probably You should use `rawurlencode()` instead of `rawurldecode()` both in `Routes.php` and in `HTML`

Comment: @JoeBlack Thank you! That solved my problem!